# Deleting segmented bar items

Tags: nativescript

I'm populating SegmentedBar items dynamically. How do I explicitly remove old SegmentedBar items?

```
private _generateSegmentedBarItemsArray( items: Array<ISelectableListItem> ): Array<SegmentedBarItem> {
    const segmentedBarItems: Array<SegmentedBarItem> = []

    for ( const dataObj of items ) {
        const segmentedBarItem = new SegmentedBarItem()

        // SegmentedBarItem require title property
        dataObj[ 'title' ] = dataObj.title
        delete dataObj.listItem

        for ( const key in dataObj ) {
            segmentedBarItem[ key ] = dataObj[ key ]
        }

        segmentedBarItems.push( segmentedBarItem )
    }

    return segmentedBarItems
}
```

Comment: By default when you set updated list of items, old items will be overwritten. Are you still facing any difficulty in updating them?

Comment: It seems to be not updating them automatically as you said. I'm getting "Binding: Binding error while setting property items of SegmentedBar(362)@file:///app/components/search/search.xml:103:25;: Error: View already has a parent. View: SegmentedBarItem(249) Parent: SegmentedBar(283)@file:///app/components/search/search.xml:103:25;"

Comment: That sounds like something to do with your code, if you can share a example where it could be reproduced, I can take a look.